# How to copy all s3 buckets to another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm copying all EC2 instances to another AWS account (creating the AMIs, sharing them with that account and running the instances from AMIs there). I also need to move my S3 buckets since the applications at EC2 instances are using that buckets to store and retrieve files.
I'd like to know if it's possible to copy all S3 buckets to my another AWS account. If yes, how could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

---

#### Update

I think I should clarify the question. My task is to make a full backup of my AWS stuff to my second AWS account so if someone will hurt anything on my current one I can easily run my instances on the second account so the system will continue working. The documents in my MongoDB (at the EC2) have records that refer to S3 files and the application is using that records. This is why I want to just move all my buckets and save the file identifiers if it's possible.

Comment: You should be able to create a bucket on the new account, set a bucket policy for each bucket granting the other account full control, and then use s3cmd to sync the new and old bucket, and then delete the old bucket. This would have to be done for one bucket at a time (it won't copy over every bucket), will result in a new bucket id, and would incur the read/write (and depending on location, data transfer) costs for all the individual objects copied. You can't just change the owner of a bucket though.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/AccessControlList.html

> Every bucket and object in Amazon S3 has an owner, the user that created the bucket or object. **The owner of a bucket or object cannot be changed.** However, if the object is overwritten by another user (deleted and rewritten), the new object will have a new owner.